# Jackson json : How to find multiple JSON nodes with same node name

Tags: json, jackson

I am trying to parse a JSON file using Jackson Json parser and in the process using the get(String nodename) function of it. 
But when i have multiple nodes of the same name , it is trying to get to the last of the similar nodes and act only on them. How do i get to all the nodes.

For example if my json file was

```
{"menu":{"a":"1", "b":"2"},
 "menu":{"c":"1", "d":"2"},
 "menu":{"e":"1", "f":"2"}}
```

and if i'm trying to do a get("menu") and try to print the field names in it, only e and f get printed whereas i want a b c d e f to get printed.

Comment: You posted the very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887584/jackson-parser-handling-of-multiplefield-names-with-same-name in the same time frame. Please don't do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably make use of [`@JsonAnySetter`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown?highlight=%28jsonanysetter%29), along the following lines.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class App
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    /* {"menu":{"a":"1", "b":"2"},"menu":{"c":"1", "d":"2"},"menu":{"e":"1", "f":"2"}} */
    String json = "{\"menu\":{\"a\":\"1\", \"b\":\"2\"},\"menu\":{\"c\":\"1\", \"d\":\"2\"},\"menu\":{\"e\":\"1\", \"f\":\"2\"}}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
    System.out.println(foo.menus);
  }
}

class Foo
{
  List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void addMenu(String key, Menu menu)
  {
    menus.add(menu);
  }
}

class Menu
{
  Map<String, Object> items = new HashMap<> ();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void addItems(String itemName, String itemValue)
  {
    items.put(itemName, itemValue);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("%s", items);
  }
}
```